# Arrow script for enemy tower to fire between random time of 0-60 seconds

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random

I do not have a script to show for i could not come across a situation like this so here it goes:

C# script

So i have my 2D sprite enemy tower and i would like the tower to shoot 5 arrows with 2 second pause between each firing at my guy who i can only move left or right, Now those times that enemy tower fires i would also like it to be random, in the range of 0-60 seconds. After tower reloads and waits for another random time to fire my rigidbody arrow sprite.

I know i cant expect someone to hold my hand and do this for me but all scripts i have come across was the player firing the arrows or enemy player usually in 3D.

Any help of guidance is very much helpful, im learning as we go.

Answer (score 3):

```
IEnumerator TowerShooting()
{
   while(true)
   {
      float timer = Random.Range(0f, 60f);
      yield return new WaitForSeconds(timer);
      float shootingTimer = 2f;
      int amountArrow = 3;
      while(amountArrow > 0)
      {
          Shoot();
          amountArrow--;
          yield return new WaitForSeconds(shootingTimer);
      }
   }
}
```

The code is fairly simple since the method naming is explicit. You have two loops, the first is infinite (somehow like Update). It first gets a waiting time and waits at the first WaitForSeconds iteration.

Then it gets to an inner loop that will run for 3 shoots, each shoot gets to wait for 2 seconds as well. Once the three shots are done, we get back to the main loop and so on until the tower is destroyed/disabled.

Comment: Very nice example given.

Comment: Thank you very much for the hep i wil attach this code to my enemy tower but this thing popped up and i have had this happen before, I know i cant ask another question but i wanted you only to help..

Comment: Shoot();
              That part of the code that says Shoot();  is underlined and keeps saying for potential fixes that i have to make

Comment: sorry i kept trying to make a new line and it posted the comment private void Shoot()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

Comment: I put the scripted attached to my enemy tower but no arrow fired...would i need a public prefab in this scripted to put my arrow into it also. Also will the arrow have an arch when fired?

Comment: Shoot is your shooting method. I do not know what you are doing there so I left it blank but likely instantiate an arrow with rigid body and then add force to it.